# What does the "page" in "function loadData(page){}" mean in my jQuery Ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following code, and I'm unsure of what the `page` in `function loadData(page){}` means? Also, the function is called later on, as `loadData(1)`. If someone could please explain what this means, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Function Definition (I think that's what it's called):**

```
function loadData(page){
    loading_show();
    gallery_hide();                    
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
        data: {page:page, imgs: value},
        success: function(msg)
        {
            $("#gallery_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                gallery_show();
                loading_hide();
                $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**1st Function Call:**

```
loadData(1);
```

**2nd Function Call:**

```
$('#gallery_container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('p');
    loadData(page);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a formal parameter representing a passed page number. It is used within the ajax call as part of the data to be sent to the server, here:

```
data: {page:page, imgs: value},
```

so if you do this:

```
loadPage(4);
```

your request will look like this:

```
new_arrivals_data.php?page=4&imgs=foo
```

This code:

```
var page = $(this).attr('p');
loadData(page);
```

calls `loadData` using the value assigned to the clicked element's 'p' attribute as its argument, which I suppose is a number.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's tough finding good resources explaining this sort of stuff. Any chance you could briefly summerize what happens in an Ajax call? I don't mean the broad idea of it. I understand that. But I mean the technical aspect of how it calls the php in this case.